# Une traduction pour « laten slingeren »

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, néerlandais

Je souhaite trouver une tournure brève exprimant que quelqu’un s’y prend mal avec ses possessions. On dit que « quelqu’un jette avec ses choses » s’il est désordonné et bordélique. 
Dans son sens littéral, « laten slingeren » veut plutôt dire « laisser pendiller » mais je laisserai cette traduction de côté, puisqu’elle paraît trop étrange dans ce cadre. Le mot « jeter » est une traduction à améliorer ici.

Il doit la perte de beaucoup de choses à son comportement. Dans sa maison, il achoppe tout ce qu’il ne souhaite pas trouver, et oublie où il a mis des trucs de grande valeur qu’il devrait bien conserver.

On le dit aussi si quelqu’un se trouve hors de la maison, et qu'il perd quelque chose. À la recherche de l’objet perdu, il perd autre chose qu’il tient dans la main. Il se rend compte de cela après avoir retrouvé ce qu’il cherchait auparavant. Des amis pourraient l'avertir : « Pourquoi jettes-tu ce que tu possèdes ? Sois un peu moins négligeant. »

C’est plus souvent quelque chose qu’on dit lorsqu’un père chapitre son enfant. Il peut prononcer la tournure pour lui remontrer son défaut de soin. Il pourrait dire « C’est déjà la dixième fois que je te dis que tu dois gérer tes choses soigneusement au lieu de les jeter. »

Tous les exemples ci-dessus laissent entendre que la tournure souligne un trait de quelqu’un. La tournure s’applique plus couramment pour indiquer comment quelqu’un agit pendant une durée donnée.

Je n’ai pas trouvé une façon de dire qui équivaut à celle-ci. J’espère que vous pourrez m'en fournir une.

Comment: « Achoppe », « chapitre », que veux-tu dire exactement ?

Comment: Je dirais "éparpiller", et même on dit souvent, ce qui semble redondant pourtant, "éparpiller un peu partout". Effectivement "pendiller" ne va pas, il y a l'idée d'être suspendu dans "pendiller".

Comment: Est-ce que « semer aux quatre vents » pourrait convenir ?

Comment: Merci ! J’ai écrit  « il achoppe des choses » pour dire qu’il retrouve ces choses aux endroits encombrants. 
Davantage chapitrer = réprimander. C’est un mot vieillot ou inhabituel ? Du moins le Wiktionnaire ne donne pas d’étiquettes qui laissent paraître qu’il soit inusité.
D’ailleurs, j’ai oublié de mettre un « comment » dans l’avant-dernière phrase. Je pense qu’il faut remplacer « que » par « comment » pour donner le propos le sens voulu.

Comment: Comment s’emploie l’expression ? Dit-on que quelqu’un « *laten slingeren* » quelque chose en particulier, ou est-ce qu’il « *laten slingeren* » de manière générale ?

Comment: Les emplois que vous suggérez ont tous les deux cours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je reprend à mon compte la réponse de Laure, que je trouve bonne : "Pourquoi jettes-tu ce que tu possèdes" se dirait en français :

- "Pourquoi mets-tu tes affaires n'importe où ?"
- "Pourquoi éparpilles-tu tes affaires ?"

Le deuxième étant plus soutenu. "affaires" est souvent utilisé pour désigner un groupe d'objets que possède quelqu'un à un endroit (comme les jouets d'un enfant, ou les vêtements d'une personne qui voyage) alors que "possessions" désigne l'ensemble des choses qu'il possède, y compris ailleurs. J'espère être clair.

Pour faire un reproche plus général à une personne, ou pourrait dire :

- "Tu devrais faire attention à tes affaires / à là où tu mets tes affaires"

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que l'on peut dire aussi dans ce cas que la personne est **distraite** ou encore **tête en l'air**.

> Mon fils est distrait, il ne sait jamais où il a laissé son ours en peluche.
>
> Ma fille est tête en l'air, elle ne se souvient jamais où elle a posé ses clés.

Tête en l'air a un peu plus la connotation de quelqu'un de rêveur, à l'esprit léger, qui ne se soucie pas beaucoup de certaines choses.

Après réflexion, je pense que l'expression **être tête de linotte** peut aussi convenir. La linotte est un oiseau qui a donc une toute petite tête et par conséquent un tout petit cerveau. Quelqu'un qui est **tête de linotte** est donc quelqu'un qui n'a pas beaucoup de mémoire, et qui oublie donc facilement les choses. On l'emploie facillement pour parler d'une personne qui oublie des choses simples comme où elle a mis ses clés, ou encore où elle a garé sa voiture.

> Quelle tête de linotte celle-là, pas moyen qu'elle se souvienne où elle a rangé son passeport alors que l'on prend l'avion dans deux heures!